# PHP execute shell command permission denied

Tags: php, macos, apache, bash, permission-denied

I installed an application (bagit) via homebrew and am trying to execute a shell command from my local Apache server (installed on OSX).

My PHP looks like this:

```
$cmd =  'bag create '.$targetFolder.' '.$sourceFolder.' --baginfotxt '.$bagInfoFile ." 2>&1";
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
```

However, I am getting the following error message:

`/bin/bash: /usr/local/bin/bag: Permission denied`

How can I give Apache access to the bash command located in `/usr/local/bin?

Comment: it's probably not the bag executable, but whatever operations bag is trying to do. e.g. you'll be running bag as the Apache userID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your apache install will need to be running as the same user/group as the files its trying to execute.

You can either change the file permissions of the application you are trying to execute to the same as apache/php current user/group (or 777 etc..)

or you can change apache/php to run as a more priviliaged user/group.

- **Alternatively**

You could change the method of your application to SSH into your executable environment and execute the application over SSH.

Comment: never do 777, it's a bad practice

Comment: Thanks. I have set the permissions on `usr/local/bin/bag` to 0777 and that seems to work. Do you know how I would be able to elevate the `_www` user? It seems that this would solve all sorts of issues, i.e. being able to write to directories outside of the server root for file manipulation.

Comment: If you modify your apache configuration, you can change the user and group that apache will run from. You can also add the apache user to the wheel group and this may help in some instances. As Rápli András stated, it is bad practice to open files and applications to the world however on your local environment the risk is minimal so long as they aren't carried into production.

Answer (score 0):

When PHP tries to exec something, it will do as the default web server user (`apache`, `www-data` or `httpd`). Make sure that the command to run has the right ownership / permissions. The easiest way to reach this is to add your web server user to a new group, lets say `test`, and `chgrp test /usr/local/bin/bag`

Comment: Do you know how to do that on OSX?

Comment: The chgrp syntax is the same for OSX afaik