# Permission Denied to execute command through SSH in php

Tags: putty

I am running a command through putty command promt. It's working fine. Now I have to do it through php script. I am using "phpseclib" library and After successfull login While executing command i am getting "Permission Denied".

How to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Likely because your PHP is running under a different user account than yours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP execute shell command permission denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827632/php-execute-shell-command-permission-denied)

Comment: Google `php execute command permission denied` for more helpful content.